# GUI not displaying correctly when called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Within my Main class, within it's main method, I have this code:

```
LogRegGUI mainMenu = new LogRegGUI();
mainMenu.setVisible(true);
```

LogRegGUI constructor:

```
public LogRegGUI() {
    initComponents();
}
```

LogRegGUI is my GUI class. My GUI displays perfectly when I right click the class and select Run.

When I run my whole program, and main is invoked, the GUI format is slightly incorrect (colour mismatch and buttons are not displayed correctly).

What am I doing wrong?

Extra info:

```
Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2
Mac OS X Mountain Lion
Java Swing
```

LogRegGUI code:

```
package com.john.spp.view;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class LogRegGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form LoginGUI
 */
public LogRegGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jEditorPane1 = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    settingsButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    helpButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    logoutButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    dataVaultButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    loginButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    registerButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jEditorPane1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(748, 134));

    settingsButton.setText("Settings");
    settingsButton.setEnabled(false);
    settingsButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    helpButton.setText("Help");
    helpButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    logoutButton.setText("Logout");
    logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
    logoutButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    dataVaultButton.setText("Data Vault");
    dataVaultButton.setEnabled(false);
    dataVaultButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(12, 12, 12)
            .add(dataVaultButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
            .add(settingsButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
            .add(helpButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
            .add(logoutButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, false)
                .add(settingsButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 122, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(helpButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(logoutButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, dataVaultButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jPanel2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    jPanel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    loginButton.setText("Login");
    loginButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    loginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            loginButtonSceneActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    registerButton.setText("Register");
    registerButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    registerButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            registerSceneButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 385, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .add(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(14, 14, 14)
                .add(loginButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(registerButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 306, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .add(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(92, 92, 92)
                .add(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, false)
                    .add(loginButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 122, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(registerButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(92, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("SPARTAN PASSWORD PROTECTOR");

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(176, 176, 176)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.CENTER)
                .add(jLabel3)
                .add(jPanel2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .add(18, 18, 18)
            .add(jLabel3)
            .add(18, 18, 18)
            .add(jPanel2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(52, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void loginButtonSceneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    LoginGUI itemloader = new LoginGUI();
    itemloader.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);  
}

private void registerSceneButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    RegisterGUI itemloader = new RegisterGUI();
    itemloader.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogRegGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogRegGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogRegGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogRegGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LogRegGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton dataVaultButton;
private javax.swing.JButton helpButton;
private javax.swing.JEditorPane jEditorPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton loginButton;
private javax.swing.JButton logoutButton;
private javax.swing.JButton registerButton;
private javax.swing.JButton settingsButton;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more code from LogRegGUI class.

Comment: Sure, it was created using Netbean's GUI builder - should I include that or leave it minimised?

Comment: Then that's your problem. Dump the NetBeans-generated code, code it up by hand, and you'll have much greater ease creating and updating your Swing GUI programs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But still, it should work fine. Who knows, more code is needed.

Comment: I know I will, but this is for a project and my supervisor has told me to use the GUI builder and not focus on the GUI. I must follow his orders. That still wouldn't explain the difference in layouts between running the class directly and creating an instance of it from another.

Comment: Without pertinent code, your problem is anyone's guess. Since much of the pertinent code is buried in NetBean's generated code bloat, good luck isolating and posting it here. Consider checking to see if the Look and Feel is different in either code base.

Comment: Added the code as requested.

Comment: So the `static void main` you've posted is the one that works correctly?  How does the full program initialize the L&F?  The only thing that makes sense is the larger program is tweaking the L&F somewhere or using a different L&F altogether. One other thing:  Java 7 is sensitive to doing all GUI initializations in the Swing event loop thread (i.e. with `InvokeLater`).  If your larger program does some initialization in the main thread, fix that.

Comment: Not a solution, but I would suggest adding an import statement for the classes you're constantly using (such as JButton and GroupLayout). Swing code can get very messy and this certainly does not help readability.

Comment: @Dan: the code you're talking about is Matisse-generated and shouldn't be touched without completely breaking it. Imports will not help this code's readability. Nothing will.

Comment: *"my supervisor has told me to use the GUI builder"*  So tell your supervisor to fix this conundrum if it is so quick and efficient.  If you want help here, your best bet is to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again just a guess, but does the other code base that tries to display your LogRegGUI GUI also use the Nimbus look and feel? Is the look and feel set before creating any GUI components in that class as well? That's my guess as to your problem.

Comment: I honestly have no idea - what you're asking is beyond my expertise. The code which creates the GUI, from my main method, is in my question. That is all I am using to call the GUI. All other GUI code is also present in my answer. How can I rectify the issue you speak of?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou: that code is not enough to solve your problem. All you have to do is search the other code base and see if it sets the look and feel as your code above does. If it doesn't then try to do so yourself. Consider borrowing the code above as an attempt, but do so off of the Swing thread and before starting the Swing thread (as is shown in your code above). You really need to read some of the Swing tutorials soon else you'll be flying blind.

Comment: OK - thanks a lot. I will have a read tomorrow and try implementing some stuff. I'll be back with my findings tomorrow.

Comment: Copied and pasted the try catch for nimbus into my main, just before I create a new instance of my GUI - it fixed my problem. I understand what it is for too - thanks a lot for your help.